# Batch file for reading names from a txt file and creating a new directory for them

Tags: batch-file, text

I' would like to read student names from a textfile (student.txt) and create a directory for each student.

I used this command:

```
for /f "tokens=1* delims=" %%i in (student.txt) do ( md %%i )
```

But when I run it and the student name is Jay Leno for example.  It makes two directory's. One Jay and one Leno.  I want only one directory, "Jay Leno"

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  I'm new to this :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for /f "delims=" %%i in (student.txt) do ( md "%%i" >nul 2>nul)
```

The directory to be created needs to be in `"quotes"` if it contains spaces (optionally if it doesn't)

The `2>nul` suppresses error mesages if the directory already exists

The `>nul` suppresses the 'created' report.

(either or both of which can be omitted at your option)

Comment: Thank you!  Now I would like to have the batch file make a directory group1 for example and have the directory's of the students made in the group1 directory.  I thought this would be easy...  Can't seem to figure it out

Comment: You'd need to create a new question - they don't cost very much - and specify how the batch is supposed to tell to which group a student belongs so the directory `group\student` can be created.

Comment: Figured it out myself.  Thank you for your help!